How can i make text bold and underline in Powershell?
I have the following
   $stringbuilder.AppendLine("name: $($obj.name )");  

I am trying to underline the name and make it bold.
I have tried to use the following definitions
   $escape = [char]27
   $underline = "${escape}[4m"
   $bold = "${escape}[1m"


$stringbuilder.AppendLine(""${escape}[4m" name: $($obj.name )""${escape}[4m");  

But how do i use these ?
How can i do this using powershell ?

If you are using the version Powershell 7 there are some types of solutions, these were the ones that really worked for me and that I think you can maybe apply.

To bold text using Convertion to Markdown:
$message = "**name**"
Write-Host ($message | ConvertFrom-Markdown -AsVT100EncodedString).VT100EncodedString

OR to bold text using Colors in the Terminal:
Write-Host 'Here is some ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor White 'bold ' -NoNewline; Write-Host 'text'

To underline text, use this ANSII escape codes:
Write-Host "Hello $([char]27)[4mWorld$([char]27)[24m"

Example of use combined Colors and Underlined with ANSII escape codes:
 Write-Host 'Text bold and underline: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host "$([char]27)[4mname$([char]27)[24m" -ForegroundColor White -NoNewline

Final output image:

Regards!

would it be the same if i am using a string builder as i want to email it ?

version of powershell is  5.1.22621

If you want to use it to send an email, you will need to put the body of the message in HTML format as shown in the following code: $bodytext = "<html><body><p><b>bold text for email</b > </p></body></html>" 

doesnt seem to work . I need to add it to a stringbuilder and then send it via email. So i only want the heading in the body as bold

This code should work for you to send the message via mail with bold text
`$stringbuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$htmlContent = @"


name: $($obj.name)


"@
$stringbuilder.AppendLine($htmlContent)
$body = $stringbuilder.ToString()`
shouldnt the line be $htmlContent = "@  name: $($obj.name)   @"   ?

if i have it $htmlContent = @"   name: $($obj.name)   "@ , it says no characters are allowd after a here-string header but before the end of the line ?
